# Equality and order in sets

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, logic, intuition, order-theory

Just started Baby Rudin and got struck in this.

While defining order in sets, $<$ was introduced as a relation and for a set to be ordered the condition was: for all $x,y$ belonging to an ordered set $C$, either $x<y$ or $y<x$ or $x=y$.

The first two are alright but how do we define the concept of $=$ in any arbitrary set. I mean $=$ ought to be a relation by itself, shouldn't it?

Comment: The identity relation is the diagonal relation. That is, something is equal only to itself.

Comment: sorry but i don't know about diagonal relation.and wouldn't saying that something is equal only to itself cause the problem about "knowing" the something quite well. e.g to say stuffs like 0.999...=1.00000.

Comment: Apostolos means that if a binary relation on a set $X$ is, by definition, a subset of $X \times X$, then the equality relation is given by the subset $\{(x, x): x \in X\}$. This is called the "diagonal" because it is identified with the graph of the function $y = x$, which in the real plane is pictured as a diagonal line with slope 1.

Comment: @quarkine: Sorry, the diagonal relation on some set $S$ is the relation $\{(a,a) : a\in S\}$. As user43208 says, it's called like that because if you want to "draw" it, it looks like a diagonal. As for your other comment, I guess you can check out [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24489/naive-set-theory-question-on) (though I guess that question is asked from the exact opposite perspective from yours - at any rate I remembered it so I though it might be helpful). The gist of it is that $0.\bar{9}$ and $1$ are different descriptions of the same object.

Comment: @Apostolos :thanks.the explanation in the link's answer is really good too.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely right! In more formal treatments of logic and set theory, the equality relation is often treated as a "God-given" relation that exists on any set. For most texts at the level of baby Rudin say, it is not formally defined, but the informal idea is that a set has been precisely specified only if the meaning of $a = b$ (identity between two elements) in the set has also been specified. For example, once the real numbers have been precisely specified, then an equation like $1 = .999\ldots$ has a definite meaning.

Properties of this equality relation include that $=$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive. Many other relations (called *equivalence relations*) also have these properties; for example, the relation on the set of people "$A$ and $B$ have the same surname" is an equivalence relation, but is not the equality relation.

Perhaps the most important property of equality is the substitution property: that $a = b$ exactly when for any meaningful property or predicate $P$ defined on the set, we have $P(a)$ if and only if $P(b)$. That is, if $a = b$, then the term $b$ can be substituted for a term $a$ in a formula $P(a)$ with no change in the truth value.

All this may seem obvious, and yet -- perhaps unbelievably -- a fuller understanding of the meaning of equality (which has probably been discussed since antiquity) has undergone some important developments within the past few years (in higher-order logic and type theory).

Comment: Thanks.This was really helpful.